# One-hot encoding in Python for array values in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, encoding

I am trying to do one-hot encoding for these clustered data frames. (grouped by length). Been trying to use sklearn's encoder but it seems to regard each individual row as one category instead of multiple.

Example input:

```
 ID                    trace  length
 3              [A, B, C, C]       4
 4           [A, B, C, C, D]       5
 5        [A, B, C, C, D, E]       6
 24             [A, B, C, C]       4
 25          [A, B, C, C, D]       5
 ...                     ...     ...
```

Expected output :

```
ID     A  B  C  D  E    length
3      1  1  1  0  0         4
4      1  1  1  1  0         5
5      1  1  1  1  1         6
24     1  1  1  0  0         4
25     1  1  1  1  0         5
.... ..... .. ......
```

Comment: Is `trace` a list or a string? Can you provide the input as DataFrame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, and if target contains lists, you could do:

```
(df.drop('trace',1)
   .join(df['trace']
         .apply('|'.join)
         .str.get_dummies()
        )
 )
```

or for in place modification of `df`:

```
df = (df.join(df.pop('trace')
              .apply('|'.join)
              .str.get_dummies())
      )
```

Or using `explode` and `pivot_table`:

```
(df.explode('trace')
   .assign(x=1)
   .pivot_table(index=['ID', 'length'], columns='trace', values='x', aggfunc='first')
   .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
   .reset_index()
 )
```

Output:

```
   ID  length  A  B  C  D  E
0   3       4  1  1  1  0  0
1   4       5  1  1  1  1  0
2   5       6  1  1  1  1  1
3  24       4  1  1  1  0  0
4  25       5  1  1  1  1  0
```